# Most efficient way to parameterize variables in Cloud Composer?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

**CONTEXT**

I'm currently using Airflow 2.4.3 in Google Cloud Composer with Python 3.8.12. I have about 100+ DAGs with approximately 4-8 tasks each and almost each task is accessing a value in Airflow Variables with `Variable.get()` method. About 90+ DAGs are running daily but there would just be a total of 15-20 DAGs that would run at the same time or in parallel.

The way I've set up and configured Airflow Variables looks like this:

```
{ 
  "config_1": {
    "key_1a": "value_1a",
    "key_1b": "value_1b"
  },
  "config_2": [
    {  
      "config_2a": {
        "common_key_1": "value_2aa",
        "common_key_2": "value_2ab"
      }
    },
    {
      "config_2b": {
        "common_key_1": "value_2ba",
        "common_key_2": "value_2bb"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**HOW I'M ACCESSING AIRFLOW VARIABLES**

There are no top level variable declarations in DAG scripts and almost all of the tasks access some value in `"config_1"` with `Variable.get("config_1", deserialize_json=True)["key_1a"]` in the parameters of each Operator.

`"config_2"` is used for generating dynamic DAGs by looping through each element with

```
for count, each_config in enumerate(Variable.get("config_2", deserialize_json=True)):
  some_variable = each_config["common_key_1"]
```

**QUESTION**

I'm wondering if this is an efficient way of using environment variables in Airflow in terms of performance and resource/workload usage.

1. Is there a more efficient way to parameterize and access variables in Airflow?
2. Will there be any difference in performance if we were to just read key-value pairs from a json file?
3. What are the best practices in parameterization when using Airflow?

---

I really appreciate your insights and advice regarding this matter. Any suggestions are very much welcome if there are some things I need to improve in this post.